# $T[f](t) = \frac{1}{t} \cdot \int_{0}^{t} f(s)ds$ is continuous and injective but not surjective

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X = C([0,1])$ be a space of continuous real functions on [0,1] and define

$$||f||_{\infty} = \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)|, \quad \forall f \in C([0,1]).$$

Consider the linear operator $T:X \rightarrow X$ defined by 
$$T[f](0) = f(0)$$
and
$$T[f](t) = \frac{1}{t} \cdot \int_{0}^{t} f(s)ds, \quad \forall t \in (0,1]$$
I want to show that $T$ is continuous, one-to-one but not onto. Here is my attempt:

Since $T$ is linear, it is enough to show that $T$ is continuous at the zero function. So we fix arbitrary $\epsilon >0$ and need to find a $\delta > 0$ such that $||f||_{\infty} < \delta$ implies $||T[f]||_{\infty} < \epsilon$. Letting $\delta = \epsilon$ yields what we want
$$||T[f]||_{\infty} \leq \sup_{t \in [0,1]} \frac{1}{t} \int_{0}^{t} |f(s)|ds < \epsilon.$$

Showing T is one-to-one seems simple enough:
$T[f_1](t)=T[f_2](t) \iff \int_{0}^{t} (f_1(s) - f_2(s)) ds \iff f_1(t) = f_2(t).$

I am stuck at ruling out that T is onto. I need to find $g \in X$ such that
$$g(t) \neq \frac{1}{t} \cdot \int_{0}^{t} f(s)ds$$
for all $f \in X$.

Comment: At least $g$ has to be differentiable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that $T$ is not onto follows from the fact that $Tf$ is differentiable at all points of $(0,1]$ and so not all continuous functions are in the range.